# Meditation to control anxiety and hyperactivity?

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-recommendation, well-being

I have recently taken up meditation to help with becoming more spiritual in general, but I am also interested in using meditation to improve my general well being.

When I am stressed and even after that (which is quite often) I tend to feel uneasy and restless in my feet and back then I get worried about my general health etc. Sympytoms only persist when I am not doing anything

How do I meditate to calm myself down and help in alliviating the spasms and restlessness due to my stress/anxiety/inability to concentrate?

Thank you and peace!

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism.SE. Not to be that guy, but I'm not sure we are well equipped to answer this sort of general self-help question. This is a site to get answers to questions about Buddhist philosophy and practice. Now, if you specify in your question which tradition you are looking for answers from, or at least that you are wondering what Buddhism says about your problem, that would probably help get quality answers.

Comment: I would say that I am looking to find out if there is a Buddhist philosophy or any kind of meditation routine that could help me channel negative thoughts away and help me take more control over myself

Comment: I get that, but this isn't really the place to look for such general help... we are a "best answer" forum, which means there should ideally be one right answer to every question. This question is both overly broad and overly opinion based for our site. As far as help goes, you're anyway likely to get conflicting answers, since meditation and Buddhism are such broad topics. Essentially, you are asking the internet for a meditation technique to help your anxiety, which probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: Arkaput, try to make another question as per Ven. Yuttadhammo's recommendation, in the meantime, try some guided metta meditation to see if it helps, usually it is good to reduce fear in the short term, as love is the opposite of fear. Anxiety is a fear of the future. Im not sure it will help because your question was too broad, but give it a try

Answer (score 2):

I think most Buddhist traditions agree that while meditating, you should concentrate on your breathing, and note when/if your mind starts to wander.  So if you have a spasm, you don't have to deny it or feel like a failure, but you recognize that it's happening, but also maintain your focus elsewhere.  You're focusing on your meditation, and whatever happens with your body goes on in spite of that because you're human, but doesn't have to detract from your focus.  You can tell your focus where to direct itself.

I know it's popular to say meditation can help with spasms and restlessness.  I think people say that because they find it teaches them to be at peace doing nothing, and that they can choose not to worry or think negative (or any) thoughts.  Personally, I'm not at that level, and I tend to become more worried when I'm not doing anything.  Perhaps for that reason, I don't schedule very long meditation sessions.  If I say I'll meditate only for 15 minutes, then I can believe that it's okay to meditate and give the meditation my full attention for that time.  If I schedule a longer time, then I have trouble really believing that it's a good use of my time, and I get fidgety.